# Is "that" used for things, people, places and time too?

Tags: relative-pronouns

So that is used for time to?

September 8 is the date that I was born.

Or

September 8 is the date when I was born.

Why is it "that" instead of "when" used in this situation, or are they both possible in this sentence?

Comment: I think "Sep 8 is **the** date that I was born" sounds weird, it'd be more common to say "the day [that] I was born". A date *that* does stuff seems weird, on the other hand I can't explain to you why "the day that I was born" sounds natural to my non-native ears.

Comment: Your question needs cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *September 8 is the date* [(*that*) *I was born **___***].
>
> [2] *September 8 is the date* [***when** I was born*].

Yes, both a *wh* and a non-*wh* relative are possible here.

In both examples, the relativised element functions as an adjunct of time within the bracketed relative clause. The only difference is that in [2] it is overt, while in [1] it is covert and marked by the gap notation '___'.

Note that in [1] the subordinator "that" is optional. Also, some speakers are likely to use "day" rather than "date" as antecedent.